# Pandas: Pack column into rows

Tags: python, pandas

I've been reading through `pd.stack`, `pd.unstack` and `pd.pivot` but I can't wrap my head around getting what I want done

Given a dataframe as follows

```py
   id1 id2  id3  vals  vals1
0    1   a   -1    10     20
1    1   a   -2    11     21
2    1   a   -3    12     22
3    1   a   -4    13     23
4    1   b   -1    14     24
5    1   b   -2    15     25
6    1   b   -3    16     26
7    1   b   -4    17     27
```

I'd like to get the following result

```py
   id1 id2  -1_vals  -2_vals  ...  -1_vals1  -2_vals1  -3_vals1  -4_vals1
0    1   a       10       11  ...        20        21        22        23
1    1   b       14       15  ...        24        25        26        27
```

It's kind of a groupby with a pivot, The column `id3` is being spread into rows, where the new column names is the corresponding concatenation of the original column and the value of `id3`

EDIT: It is guaranteed that per `id1` + `id2` `id3` will be unique, but some groups of `id1` + `id2` will have diffenet `id3` - in this case it is ok to put `NaN`s there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) and [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) for `MultiIndex` in columns and then flatten it by list comprehension with `f-string`s:

```
df1 = (df.set_index(['id1','id2','id3'])
         .unstack()
         .sort_index(level=[0,1], ascending=[True, False], axis=1))

#python 3.6+
df1.columns = [f'{b}_{a}' for a, b in df1.columns]
#python below
#df1.columns = ['{}_{}'.format(a, b) for a, b in df1.columns]
df1 = df1.reset_index()
print (df1)
   id1 id2  -1_vals  -2_vals  -3_vals  -4_vals  -1_vals1  -2_vals1  -3_vals1  \
0    1   a       10       11       12       13        20        21        22   
1    1   b       14       15       16       17        24        25        26   

   -4_vals1  
0        23  
1        27
```